# Tracing a WPF element on a canvas

Tags: wpf, animation

I am exploring WPF animation and easing functions. I have an element on a canvas that is animated when I click on it. The X and Y positions of the transform when I click on the element.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAnimationExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAnimationExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EllipseEasing" TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="260" Duration="0:0:5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="130" Duration="0:0:5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Canvas Name="Canvas">
    <Ellipse Name="MainEllipse" Style="{StaticResource EllipseEasing}" Canvas.Top="30" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown" />
</Canvas>
```

This all works.

I am trying to graphically see the trace of the elements motion. I desired to draw a clone of the element wherever it was every 100 ms but I don't know how to grab the current position of the element in the canvas at only one instant.

I added a parallel handler when I click the element but that doesn't seem to work...

```
private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new ThreadStart((async () =>
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++)
            {

                try
                {
                    var x = Canvas.GetLeft(MainEllipse);
                    var y = Canvas.GetTop(MainEllipse);

                    var rx = ((TranslateTransform)MainEllipse.RenderTransform).X;
                    var ry = ((TranslateTransform)MainEllipse.RenderTransform).Y;
                    Ellipse newControl = new Ellipse { Height = MainEllipse.Height, Width = MainEllipse.Width, Fill = Brushes.Blue };
                    Canvas.SetLeft(newControl, rx);
                    Canvas.SetTop(newControl, ry);
                    Canvas.Children.Add(newControl);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    throw;
                }
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }

        })));

    }
```

Suggestions?
TIA

Comment: You are animating a TranslateTransform  in the RenderTransform of the Ellipse. That won't magically set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties.

Comment: I see that. How can I get the actual position of the ellipse at any one time?

Comment: @Jeff: Did you try to access the property that is actually being animated?, e.g.: `((TranslateTransform)newControl.RenderTransform).X;`.

Comment: Or just animate Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top to certain target values, without setting the animations' From values.

Comment: I just updated with mm8 suggestion  - closer - no cigar yet

Comment: You do realize that Left/Top and TranslateTransform are additive? To keep things simple, use only one of those mechanisms.

Comment: I animated top end left (after initializing them so I avoided the NaN and got it working.  Thank you. Don't know how to upvote you.

Comment: After playing with - both of these solutions worked.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that RenderTransform is typically slightly more efficient, because no layout is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the "current" value, you should access the property that is actually being animated, e.g.:

```
((TranslateTransform)newControl.RenderTransform).X
```

...assuming you animate the `X` property of the `RenderTransform`.